# Cannot upgrade postgis extension. Getting error that postgis has no update path

Tags: django, database, postgresql, postgis

I have installed postgres database using it in my django app.
I started getting this error that

django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.5": No such file or directory

So I decided to update postgis to 2.5
ERROR:  extension "postgis" has no update path from version "2.5.2" to version "2.5.0"

Is there a wayout.

Comment: Can you add the commands you used to install the postgis libraries into your operating system? Also, please add the postgres version you have installed. cheers

Comment: Are you saying that it was working at one point and then suddenly stopped working for no reason?  If your installation has disappeared, changing its minor version is not going to make it come back.

Comment: @jjanes Yes It was working before and then I installed mysql database on ubuntu database and I remember removing and upgrading some packages also. Now when I try to run development environment which is linked to postgres db. I get that error. What could be the possible solution should I remove the database and reinstall it or it is something out of the database but a binary somewhere.

Comment: @JimJones I used CREATE EXTENSION postgis to install postgis in postgresql database. Since this error occured I am using ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE to "2.5.1"; to alter the extension to remove the error. But it also gives another error which is ERROR:  extension "postgis" has no update path from version "2.5.2" to version "2.5.0"